# Powershell 6.2 and Get-CimInstance to remotely stop/start/restart service issues

Tags: powershell, windows-services, powershell-core, powershell-v6.0

So I am at a big roadblock right now. I was working in PowerShell 5.1 and had the `Get-WmiObject` with the `Win32_Service` Class working perfectly fine to remotely stop/start/restart services remotely. However, I found out that the `.StopService()` method has been removed in PowerShell 6 (which I used this to bypass the dependencies issues I kept running in to). As well, I have found out that the `-ComputerName` variable has also been removed from a lot of the different commandlets.

Since the removed the `-ComputerName` from things like the `Stop-Service` commandlet, I am struggling to figure out how to properly handle the stopping of the service itself. I can retrieve the service or services I want without issue. I just can't seem to figure out how to handle stopping the service.

Tried being as detailed as I can. I know I am missing something stupidly small, but all of my Google searches appear to return everything with PowerShell 5, but so little on 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, nevermind about this question. I decided to approach my Google searching another way and I stumbled upon the syntax I needed. For those of you wondering, you cannot run commands straight from the returned object. So for example, you could do "$service.StopService()" straight on the service previously. However, now you have to do an invoke of that StopService method by doing "Invoke-CimMethod -Name StopService" and that is only after you pipe the Get-CimInstance returned object to it. So the full syntax would look something like this.

```
get-ciminstance win32_service -filter "Name='spooler'" | Invoke-CimMethod -Name StartService
```

A really good website I found to explain and give really good examples of why and how the Cim Instances are they way they are.

https://4sysops.com/archives/managing-services-the-powershell-way-part-7